# Rasterize will output 0 as NODATA (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation

I have a data range which includes 0 ex +3 to -4. I would like the rasterize to include my 0 data (create a pixel) and just exclude the NODATA (where there is no points)

Comment: Have you tried setting the output extent to use layer extent and selecting the input layer? You could then set the No Data value to -999 or something to see if it stays